# Soldering time for HC49 through-hole crystal without damaging it

Tags: microcontroller, pcb, soldering, impedance, crystal

I do a lot of circuits using through-hole technology, but one part that just does not want to work perfectly every time is the HC49/S crystal even though it is installed correctly.

When I replace one crystal with another one of the same frequency, the crystal works correctly.

I am wondering:

Is there a limit on how long the hot solder tip can touch the crystal lead before a crystal malfunctions?

The reason I ask is because the PCB tracks I make for the crystals are about 2mm wide to lower the impedance between the crystal and the microcontroller and I want to make the connections smooth.

Datasheets with crystals are hard to come by because I order many on ebay, and some from futurlec.com and some from a local shop.

Comment: This is unlikely to be an issue, still 2mm wide tracks was probably not a good choice; notice no one else designs things that way, and you aren't going to get a crystal in an HC49 where that really matters - rather, keep them short.  More likely you've got either bad crystals from a dodgy source, or an oscillator circuit that is really marginal for the crystal.

Comment: you don't need to worry about the impedance of traces between the MCU and the Crystal.

Comment: soooo don't order HC49 crystals from ebay? Why would you even do that? It's hard to imagine for me you're even saving money by doing that; these crystals start at 6ct (€) [at reputable electronics distributors](https://www.arrow.com/en/products/search?prodLine=Crystals&promoGroupLevel=pl&filters=Standard+Package+Name:HC-49;&sortBy=calculatedPrice&sortDirection=asc) that ship them for free **and have datasheets**  for every single one of them. Cheap electronic components from ebay – simply don't.

Comment: Well, I did save money on other parts on ebay like LEDs that worked and sometimes the price difference is huge. Even if I got one blown up 3-color LED in the mail and a perfect 3-color LED all for 25 cents, that's alot cheaper than local stores because they want at least $1.50 for EACH LED!

Comment: so, honestly, getting one damaged and one working LED for 25 ct in the mail makes me 25 ct poorer and gives me zero LEDs I trust. So, literally every price at a reputable distributor is cheaper, because I get something I trust for my money. That's exactly happening here: you can't trust your components, hence you waste time even considering whether they'd be at fault.  Honestly, nothing illustrates that you don't actually save anything by buying questionable components. Simply don't. As said, I *heavily* doubt you saved buying oscillators from ebay. Have you checked the product list I linked?

Comment: A few things are still great on ebay like connectors, but now I'm gonna limit all my IC purchases (including crystals) to reputable distributors because it is more than once I had issues with IC's on that site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

• Do not forcibly spread or bend the leads into a socket or PCB holes. This will avoid cracking the glass insulation around the leads of the component.

• Do not apply excessive soldering heat – Recommended Maximum Temperature is 380 ̊C using a hand soldering iron for a Maximum Duration of 3 seconds.

If you neglect these rules, you may damage performance. Using non-franchised distributors with no warranty  or support is a high risk.

REF [Abracon](https://abracon.com/uploads/resources/appendix-f.pdf)

Miniature THT Xtals are < $0.5 (1). HC-49 about $1.50

Comment: "...maximum duration of 3 seconds..." .. That probably explains it because when I solder, I normally spend 3-4 seconds a component. Maybe I just shouldn't focus so much on the smooth clean joint. My soldering iron is 30 watt and my room is semi-cool so I might be OK with temperature.

Comment: 5mm LEDs are 5 s max but I have found if too close to base, 3s max. Techniques to achieve depend on oxidation and flux.

Comment: I'm using rosin-core solder (MGchemicals "RA" in a pink tube) https://www.mgchemicals.com/products/solder-and-accessories/solder-wire/leaded-cored-solder-wire/sn-60-/-pb40-solder-wire/sn60-pb40-4890

Comment: If copper is not oxidized, no problem

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a limit on how long the hot solder tip can touch the crystal lead before a crystal malfunctions?

Yes, but its absurdly long.  If you get two or three data sheets for comparable crystals from two or three reputable crystal manufacturers then you should find some guidance, and it should more or less apply to any *decent* crystal.

Basically, if you're not destroying your TO-92 cased transistors, and if you're not subjecting your crystals to mechanical stress, then your crystals will be fine.

Comment: To get a question that answers your *problem*, post your schematic and layout with the title "Why are my crystal oscillators unreliable?"  It would be good to do [a search on "crystal oscillator layout"](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=crystal+oscillator+layout) on this group before then -- your answer may be out there just waiting for you.

Comment: Is there a way to identify what manufacturer is and isn't reputable because I think some crystals I ordered on ebay didn't work. then a few times when I replaced one crystal with another of the same frequency, things worked. Also, the layout is basic. micro's crystal pins to crystal, and each crystal pin to a grounded 33pF capacitor. I also upgraded my capacitors to 5% npo from the existing 20% ceramic.

Comment: Buy **from a known manufacturer** and **through a distributor**.  eBay is a flea market, where you buy unknown stuff at deep discounts.  Ask yourself how much you've saved by buying parts through eBay, how much time you've spent *because* you bought parts through eBay, and how much your time is worth.  Then do the math, and as yourself why you're not buying from a source you can trust.

Comment: exactly. The reason distributors (like the one I linked to in my comment to your question) are **sometimes** (not probably the case here) more expensive than random ebay sellers is that they do the supplier choice for you. If I buy a component from mouser, digikey, arrow, rs components, … I get a working component. Full stop. I hope you wouldn't be like this when it comes to buying brake components for your car: "Oh, I've had bad experiences with failing brakes before, but ebay is 50% cheaper, so what's a life worth, anyway?"

Comment: Yes, I spent more time with ebay, but sometimes people have a budget as well. Some places are more expensive than others. I actually ordered 6 high-speed microcontrollers from Digikey and one of them malfunctioned upon arrival but the next one in the package completely worked.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility (assuming you are using the crystal as part of a tuning fork design as a micro's clock) is that you are not giving it the proper load capacitance.  This could mean it's oscillating too slow or too fast for your micro.

I'm guessing this as a possibility because you mentioned not having a datasheet for the crystals.  You have to get the frequency and the load capacitance right.

Adafruit has a good explanation of this on their site.  But your micro's datasheet should provide the appropriate crystal frequency and load capacitance.
https://blog.adafruit.com/2012/01/24/choosing-the-right-crystal-and-caps-for-your-design/

Comment: Too slow or Too fast won't be an issue unless the oscillation speed is actually over 24Mhz. But I am using 5% npo capacitors. I'm gonna try ordering crystals from any place but ebay, and see if that makes the world a difference because the circuit I'm doing is an exact duplicate of one I've done before and the one before works fine. I still can't figure out the best manufacturer of crystals to choose.